# Add Admob ads to a android app not on market?

Tags: android, admob, google-play

I'm new to admob and adding ads to my applications. I have added the google play services sdk to my project(app) and added a add view to the the layout of my app. Everything is set up properly and the test ads show up when debugging the app on my android device. I wanted to know if I didnt launch/publish the app to google play but people still downloaded the apk... Will i still be able to make money from the in app ads when the users click on the ads and does admob pay for the views for a ads?

Admob ad got a yellow triangle next to it saying linking to market so I'm a little confused on if I have to link to the market to make the ads work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it doesn't matter if it's on the market or not. You don't have to link the yellow triangle to your app it just makes the icon and name for it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply:) I made an app and google suspended it from google play because they think its a spam. So i was thinking to release it on other markets and was wondering if the ads will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Im using admob and i released my apps on playstore and samsung market. I even have some apps that only available on samsung market, so far i never had any issue from the earning. So yes, the ads will still appears regardless of what market you put your apps into